# Why is my TableView with WebView loading strangely (every 3rd object in array)

Tags: ios, uitableview, webview

I have UITableView with UIWebView in it.

Before I load UITableView, I fetch some JSON on another thread

```
-(void)fetchJson
{
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    NSString* url = ...
    NSData* theData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    @try {
        NSError *error;

        NSMutableArray* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                                JSONObjectWithData:theData
                                options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves
                                error:&error];

        if (error){
            NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
            NSLog(@"if");
        }
        else{
            ...
                // here I fetch a string which holdshtml and MathML data in it.
                NSString *eq_text = [question objectForKey:@"eq_text"];
                stq.question = eq_text;

            ...

        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Exception");
    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        _counter = _questionsArray.count;
        [_tableView reloadData];

    });

});
```

This is how I loadRequest to WebView

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

...
[cell.webView loadRequest:[self readMathMlString:question.question]];
...
return cell;

}
```

With method [self readMathMlString:eq_text] I make NSUrlRequest. I have some MathJax That I need to show in the WebView, And I have to show it this way

```
-(NSURLRequest*)readMathMlString:(NSString*)content{

NSString *tmpFileName = @"test1.html";

//temp dir
NSString *tempDir = NSTemporaryDirectory();

//create NSURL
NSString *path4 = [tempDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:tmpFileName];
NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path4];

//setup HTML file contents
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MathJax" ofType:@"js" inDirectory:@"MathJax-2.2-latest"];

//write to temp file "tempDir/tmpFileName", set MathJax JavaScript to use "filePath" as directory, add "xContent" as content of HTML file
[self writeStringToFile:tempDir fileName:tmpFileName pathName:filePath content:content];

NSURLRequest* req = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

//original request to show MathJax stuffs
//[myWebView loadRequest:req];

return req;
}
```

So, the problem is, for some reason data is shown in the strange order.
When the View is open for the first time, app shows first 4 cells appearing absolutely same, but they shouldn't be.

See example below:

[image: This is the screenshot of what it's shown]
[image: This is what it should be shown]

This is the screenshot of what is shown:
This is NSLog of data that should be show
From here, we can see that for some reason, it displays all 4 cells with the data from what should be the 3rd cell.

Also, when i scroll my table view down and then up again, the data in WebView changes again.
Example:
[image]

What could be the cause of all this and how to solve it?

Comment: So is the data you retrieve correct, or not?

Comment: The data is correct, but not displayed properly. As mentioned, instead of showing data in order, TableView shows first 4 cells of same data *data from the3rd cell, for example)

Comment: So why have you posted the code that retrieves and processes the data rather than the tableview datasource methods?

Comment: How does `question.question` change for different rows?